# How to call a method(function) of a plugin from outside of that plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, jquery-plugins

I know this is an old question in stackoverflow. But for me it is new, I have searched for a solution but I didn't got a solution which I can understand. I have a plugin, in that I have some functions. Now I want to access one of the function when an event changes on `select options`. But my problem is I'm not able access the function from outside of the plugin. However I'm new to plugin development.

here is my plugin :

```
    (function($, window, document, undefined) {
    var Spec = {
        init: function(options, ele) 
        {
            var self = this;
            self.elem = ele;
            self.$elem = $(ele);

            self.findPro = (typeof options === 'string') ? self.findPro = options : self.findPro = options.findPro;
            self.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.specpro.options, options);
            if (self.options.findPro === 'latest') {
                self.latestPro();
            }
        },
        latestPro:function(){
            var results=['x','y','z','zx'];
var pinSelector = $('<select/>').addClass('form-control chzn-select  chzn-rtl').attr({'data-placeholder': 'Add pins to filter',
                'multiple': true, 'id': 'pinSelector'}).append($('<option/>').attr('value', ''));
   $.each(results,function(i,item){
       pinSelector.append($('<option/>').attr('value',item).text(item));
   });

pinSelectorCt = $('<div/>').addClass('col-lg-12').append(pinSelector);
    $('#lp').append(pinSelectorCt);
$(".chzn-select").chosen();

        },
        filter:function(filFor){
            this.html('zzz');

        }
    };
    $.fn.specpro = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var spec = Object.create(Spec);
            spec.init(options, this);
        });
    };
    $.fn.specpro.options = {
        findPro: 'latest'
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

And what I tried is :

```
$(function(){
 var mn=$('#lp').specpro({findPro:'latest'});
 $('.chzn-select').chosen().change().mn.filter('latest');
});
```

Can anyone tell me. How can I call the function `filter` from outside of the plugin.

Live [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywL9e/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution is to expose the plugin instance itself like

```
$.fn.specpro = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var spec = Object.create(Spec);
        spec.init(options, this);
        $(this).data('specpro', spec)
    });
};
```

then

```
var specpro = $('#lp').data('specpro');
specpro.filter();//call which ever method you want
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H44FL/)